# Count I do a preg_replace where I run the match trough a dictionary and use it as the item that gets placed?

Tags: php, regex

I want to do a regular expression to find the month in `$startDate`. So if the month would be 11 Mei 2020 I would like to replace Mei with 05. I would like to do this by running `match[0]` through a dictionary to get the correct corresponding number. How can I do this?

```
function doGetEarliestUpcomingDate($today, $dates)
    {
        foreach($dates as $date)
        {   
            $startDate = $date['startdatum'];
            preg_replace('/ (.*?) /', this.do_dutch_month_name_to_number($match[0]),  $startDate);
        }
    }

    function doDutchMonthNameToNumber($monthName){
        $monthName = strtolower($monthName);
        $monthDictionary = array(
            'januari' => '01',
            'februari' => '02',
            'maart' => '03',
            'april' => '04',
            'mei' => '05',
            'juni' => '06',
            'juli' => '07',
            'augustus' => '08',
            'september' => '09',
            'oktober' => '10',
            'november' => '11',
            'december' => '12',
        );
        return $monthDictionary[$monthName];
    }
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Comment: When I use the preg_replace_callback it also replaces the spaces is it possible to keep the original spaces?

Comment: Probably easiest to have your callback function return the replacement with a leading and trailing space added directly. (You are only matching one single space character before and after here, so it’s not like the could be different kinds of whitespace anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the match only, you could make use of `\K` to forget what was currently matched, and use a positive lookahead `(?=` to make sure there is a horizontal whitespace `\h+` following and 4 digits.

```
\b\d+\h+\K[a-z]+(?=\h+\d{4})\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/30Tmag/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/SsCNV)

Using [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), you could add the single match to the function `doDutchMonthNameToNumber`

For example

```
$replaced = preg_replace_callback('/\b\d+\h+\K[a-z]+(?=\h+\d{4})\b/i', function($matches){
    return $this->doDutchMonthNameToNumber($matches[0]);
}, $startDate);
echo $replaced; // 11 05 2020
```

---

Instead of using `\K`, you could also use capturing groups and add the second capturing group `$matches[2]` to the function.

```
\b(\d+\h+)([a-z]+)(\h+\d{4})\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3SgyyK/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/Hl8Je)